# JSOUP: Error while getting image's absolute url

Tags: image, url, jsoup, absolute

I'm getting a error while using jsoup to  get the image's absolute url.

## code:

```
package org.zzz.parser;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

public class DocumentParser {
    /**
     * Parsing html from file
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String url = "www.guiabh.com.br/evento/back-in-jack-seu-madruga.aspx";

        File input = new File("/home/thalesfc/Code/recSystem/wgetao/" + url);

        Document doc = null;

        // parsing the document
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "ISO8859-1", url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("$ Erro ao fazer o parsing do arquivo: " + input.getName());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //getting the image url
        Element image = doc.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderConteudo_controleInternoAgito1_imageFotoCasa");
        String imageUrl = image.attr("src");
        String imageRealUrl = image.absUrl("src");
        String imageRealUrl2 = image.attr("abs:src");

        System.out.println("# image: " + imageUrl);
        System.out.println("# real image: " + imageRealUrl);
        System.out.println("# real image 2: " + imageRealUrl2);
    }
}
```

## output:

# image: ../imgs_cadastradas/seu madruga.jpg

# real image:

# real image 2:

The desirable output is:  http://www.guiabh.com.br/imgs_cadastradas/seu madruga.jpg

Am I doing something wrong??

Answer (score 0):

You're looking in the "www.guiabh.com.br/evento/back-in-jack-seu-madruga.aspx" URL.

When you get the image url, it starts with "../", which means to bak one lvl.

To put it simply it goes back to "www.guiabh.com.br/evento/" + the image url.

It throws the error, cause you are trying to connect here: "../imgs_cadastradas/seu madruga.jpg"

I'd avise to have a method to get the URL from where you got the image, and than anticipate what I said above.